# Uncheck an entity radio in webform and remove the value from computed twig

Tags: radio-button, twig, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I use the webforms module to create a form. I have two entity radios elements and a computed twig element, in which I show the choices from the radio button. I want to be able to uncheck the radio button and remove the values form the computed twig too. With jQuery, I managed to make possible to uncheck the radio buttons but I can't remove the value from the computed twig.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can't. You can't interact with `twig` clientside as `twig` is run serverside

Comment: @DarkBee I develop my site on a server.

Comment: [difference between client- and serverside programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)